# MDX filtering in PowerBI

Tags: powerbi, mdx

I'm importing data from a cube but since the whole cube is too big for Power BI I have to use MDX to filter it out.

I'm new to MDX and so far I've come up with this code:

```
SELECT NON EMPTY Hierarchize({DrilldownLevel({[Stores POS].[Type hierarchy].[All types]},,,INCLUDE_CALC_MEMBERS)}) ON COLUMNS , NON EMPTY Hierarchize({DrilldownLevel({[Stores POS].[POS hierarchy].[All POS]},,,INCLUDE_CALC_MEMBERS)}) ON ROWS  FROM [Receipts Cube] WHERE ([Time].[Time].[Calendar Year].&[2020],[Measures].[Count of Receipts])
```

This all works in SSMS the way it has to. Left column with store names etc. But when I copy that code to PBI the stores names disappear and instead I have "[Stores POS].[POS hierarchy].[All POS]" for each value where a Store name should be. I'm guessing PBI doesn't like hierarchizing but when trying to remove it I can't get the code to work at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
NON EMPTY {[Stores POS].[Type hierarchy].[WinPOS], [Stores POS].[Type hierarchy].[SelfCheckout]} ON COLUMNS,
NON EMPTY {[Stores POS].[POS hierarchy].[Store]} ON ROWS
FROM [Receipts Cube])
WHERE ([Time].[Time].[Calendar Year].&[2020],[Measures].[Count of Receipts])
```